# JavaScript onClick button adds textarea into particular div elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am obviously missing something. I need this addmore button to add textarea into the div for the particular question, not only the first one. I can make it complicate, but I hope there is an easy solution.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Mr7/)

**index.html**

```
1.Question:<br/>
<textarea name="odg1" rows="1" cols="50" ></textarea><br/><div id="inner"></div><button type="button" name="addmore" onClick="addmore();">Add more</button>
<br/><br/>
2.Question:<br/>
<textarea name="odg2" rows="1" cols="50" ></textarea><br/><div id="inner"><button type="button" name="addmore" onClick="addmore();">Add more</button>
<br/><br/>
```

**addmore.js**

```
am = 1;
function addmore() {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "odg" + am;
        textarea.rows = 1;
        textarea.cols = 50;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = textarea.outerHTML;
        document.getElementById("inner").appendChild(div);
        am++;
}
```

Comment: you cannot use the same id for multiple elements

Comment: FYI, IDs **must** be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function demonstrates how to generate more element using jQuery:

```
var am = 1;
function addmore() {
    var newText = $('<textarea />').attr('name','odg'+am).attr('rows',1).attr('cols',50);
    var newBtn = $('<button />').attr('onclick','addmore()').html('add more');
    $('body').append(newText);
    $('body').append('<br />');
    $('body').append(newBtn);
    am++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see, but this adds only one text area. I want to make the buttons add limitless number of textareas under each question.

Comment: I will make an edit. This is not clear in your question.

Comment: If you're comfortable using jQuery this gets a lot easier. If so, let me know and I will post a solution. Doing this in plain JS is a lot more work.

Comment: If this is easier, it should be great. Thank you. Edit the question because maybe I was a bit onfusing